# cakephp ACL check if user has permission to execute action in current controller

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, cakephp-1.3, acl

what's the syntax to check if the user has permission to execute a certain controller action in the current controller using the ACL component of cakePHP?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
$this->Acl->check(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => $id), 'controller/action');
```